# Does the PayPal Direct Payment API support setting up recurring payments?

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

Does the new [PayPal Direct Payments API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPDirectPayments) include access/support for [Recurring Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments)?

I'm not clear if the new Direct Payments API offers access to all the API routines, or just plain old credit card processing. [This document from PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside) makes it seem like the answer is no, but it's not clear.

Our goal is to replace Authorize.net with PayPal, where the user stays on our site and the actual credit card processor is transparent to the end user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is under the Handling Recurring Payments section [Recurring Payments With Direct Payments](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_WPRecurringPayments#id08669F0705Z). It appears it is supported.

Comment: Whoa, epic fail that I missed that. Thanks!